# SQLite with Kivy on Android

Tags: android, python, sqlite, kivy

I have a Kivy app and I use SQLite 
Works fine as I work on Win 10 or Ubuntu
But when I install the apk on Android I have problems

I use Buildozer VN for the apk , apk seems to work fine
When I install it on android,  app crashes in time of saving

I guess I have to intilize the SQLite database file on android
My question is how and where to do this.
My app is a small tutorial and  I have the db file in root of main.py
I use this command :

```
 con = sqlite3.connect('demo.db')
```

Where must I put the demo.db on android in order to use it by my app?

Thanks a lot

Kostas

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import os
app_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
con = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(app_path, 'demo.db'))
```

Note: If you want to upload the db when building the app maybe you should include the extension in buildozer.spec file

```
    # (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas, ttfs, json, db
```